# BDD with Cucumber to guide Chef development

Tags: cucumber, chef-infra, bdd

I like a lot Cucumber and I find a very useful tool to solve problems seeing them with an outside-in approach so I would like to use it as part of chef projects too. I have successfully integrated it into the project I'm working on but at the time of writing business goal of features I have some doubts.

Who is the end user here? 
Regarding on this the feature will be more service oriented or not, ie: 
If the feature is more architecture faced the I could write a MongoDB feature which describes that I need up and running a MongoDB service and that the applications is linked to it.
In the other hand I should just write application features, forgetting about the infrastructure behind and then assume that if the cucumber tests run well for the application then it means that the infrastructure is fine too. (I dont like this approach)

Which of the both approaches are better? I like the most the first one but I'm just a noob on these lands. Please give me your considerations.

Comment: checkout: http://serverspec.org/

Comment: Here's book how you might do BDD with Chef http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030973.do